# NodeJs Function unable to return callback response

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have a utility function, which is reading a private key from the filesytem and then creating a JWT token,
The code is able to read the file and create a token as well,
But it is unable to callback to the calling function,
there is no error as well.

**Following is the function code -**

```
let async = require('async');
let fs   = require('fs');
let path   = require('path');
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = {
    createToken
};

const TAG = '[COMMON-UTIL->';

function createToken(constants, payload, options, keyName, callback){
    const METHOD_TAG = TAG + 'createToken]->';

        async.waterfall([
            function(callback) {
                let keyPath = 'somePathHere';

                fs.readFile(keyPath, 'utf8', function(err, privateKey) {
                    if(err){
                        callback(err, null);
                    }
                    else{
                        callback(null, privateKey);
                    }
                });
            },
            function(privateKey, callback) {
                jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, options, function(err, token) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(METHOD_TAG, err);
                        callback(err, null);
                    }
                    else{
                        callback(null, token);
                    }
                });
            }
        ],
        function(err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(METHOD_TAG, err);
                callback(err, null);
            } 
            else {
                callback(null, token);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I don't see any error the code. Can you do console.log in the last callback and check what is it printing there?

Comment: I ran the code using VSCode debugger, 
I could see the token value, 
But then it just disappears, no error ass well

Comment: How are you calling "createToken" function?

Comment: commonUtil.createToken(constants, tokenPayload, refreshTokenSignOptions, function(err, refreshToken) {//code here }

Comment: I see you are missing one parameter while calling createToken utility. CreateToken utility is expecting 4 parameters and the 5th one is the callback.Your callback should be a 5th parameter. You can try calling as 
  commonUtil.createToken(constants, tokenPayload, refreshTokenSignOptions, ' ', function(err, refreshToken) {//code here }

Comment: oh damn, you're right, missing one param while calling.

Answer (score 0):

Lexical scope issue for callback. Try changing code as show below:

```
const async = require('async');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// const TAG = '[COMMON-UTIL->';
// const METHOD_TAG = TAG + 'createToken]->';

let createToken = (constants, payload, options, keyName, callback) => {
    async.waterfall([
        (async_callback) => {
            let keyPath = 'somePathHere';
            fs.readFile(keyPath, 'utf8', (err, privateKey) => {
                if (!err) {
                    async_callback(null, privateKey);
                } else {
                    async_callback(err);
                }
            });
        },
        (privateKey, async_callback) => {
            jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, options, (err, token) => {
                if (!err) {
                    async_callback(null, token);
                } else {
                    async_callback(err);
                }
            });
        }
    ], (err, token) => {
        callback(err, token);
    });
};


module.exports = {
    createToken
};
```

Hope this fixes the issue.